# Триггер добавления данных в таблицу PostgreSQL

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

У меня есть 4 таблицы (фото ниже) : таблицы деталей (details), поставщиков (provider), поставок (shipment) и проектов (project).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая из них содержит одноимённую информацию. Мне нужно написать триггер, который бы не позволял добавить новую поставку в таблицу shipment, если поле rating таблицы provider меньше 6 и поле price таблицы detail больше 1000.

Я попытался написать его, но он явно работает некорректно, пропуская недопустимые значения. Почему данный триггер не работает?

Код триггера и триггерной функции:

```
CREATE TRIGGER provider_control_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON shipment FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE provider_control()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION provider_control() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE 
    rating bigint;
    price bigint;
BEGIN
    rating = provider.rating FROM provider WHERE (provider.id = NEW.from_id);
    price = detail.price FROM detail WHERE (detail.id = NEW.detail_id);
    IF rating < 6 AND price >= 1000 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error';
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятней всего у вас не создалась хранимая функция из-за ошибок в ней. Если так, то значит и триггер не создался.

В функции непонятная конструкция

```
rating = provider.rating FROM provider WHERE (provider.id = NEW.from_id);
```

Вероятней всего вы хотите получить в переменную **rating** значение из таблицы, по условию. Но это так не работает.

Правильнее будет

```
SELECT provider.rating FROM provider WHERE (provider.id = NEW.from_id) INTO rating;
```

По второй переменной так же переписываете.

Это то что бросается сразу в глаза.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, оно действительно работает! Но как выяснилось оно работало и при моём варианте, я просто неправильно подобрал тестовые данные. Вам огромное спасибо за помощь!